# Do until____or until____ loop

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make two conditions for a loop?

Essentially I want to do the following:

```
Sub SubMac4_1Loop()

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "X"
    **or until ActiveCell.Offset(1,1) = ""**
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Loop
End Sub
```

Obviously this won't work, but I need to know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for an OR boolean condition.

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "X" OR ActiveCell.Offset(1,1) = ""
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Loop
```

More information on VBA's `Do [Until]/[While] Loop` syntax is available from the MSDN site at [Do...Loop Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx).

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: I love how you link to that question (avoid select/activate) in pretty much every answer I see you post ;-)

Comment: This one is particularly important as the user is relying on the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) to shift as rows are deleted. Not a 'best practice' in my estimation. There are so many things that could go wrong you might as well be programming Word VBA (ewww!).